# Incorrect target of \label link produced by hyperref

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing

In the following code, the command `\label{my}` appears on page 4, as well `\pageref{my}` says "4", but the hyperlink points to the page one. Why is that?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

  % Four pages of text.
  \lipsum[1-20] 

  % The label is on fourth page.
  \label{my}    

  % Buggy pageref. It produces the number 4, but the link leads to the first page.
  \pageref{my} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Most definitely *not* a bug. The `\label` command attaches a marker to the nearest structure -- \section, \caption, etc -- that can receive an anchor. Your document has no anchorable structures at all; hence the default anchor, the start of the document, applies. Use the \pantomsection command to create additional anchors for \label commands.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It's not a bug; there's no anchor; `\label` by itself does not place an hyperlink-anchor, so obviously your hyperlink won't take you to the place where you placed `\label`; you can use `\phantomsection` to create an anchor at a given location:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-20] 

\phantomsection\label{my}\newpage 

\pageref{my} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: This solves "how to fix". For an answer to the initial question ("why") see the comment by Mico in the op.