# Make a reference to a page containing a certain sentence?

Tags: cross-referencing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When do I need invoke \phantomsection?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44088/when-do-i-need-invoke-phantomsection)
>   [Incorrect link produced by hyperref](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49061/incorrect-link-produced-by-hyperref)

I want to reference a page containing a certain sentence. If I add a label to the sentence and use `\pageref{ref}`, then this refers/links to the page containing the section title. Is there anyway to force the reference to stay near the sentence in which it is placed?

Comment: you need to define an acnchor for the label. try to use `\phantomsection` before the `\label{sentence}`

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly. I didn't know about `\phantomsection`. If you formulate it as an answer, I can mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As explained [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44088/when-do-i-need-invoke-phantomsection) `\phantomsection` is required by [`hyperref`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) to find an anchor to jumpt to. Chapters, sections, figures, tables, and other environments set this automatically, but for random labels you need to write `\phantomsection\label{mylabel}`.