# How do I associate a label with a non-section document element?

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Incorrect target of \label link produced by hyperref](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49061/incorrect-target-of-label-link-produced-by-hyperref)

Labeling and linking in LaTeX confuses me.

I have something like the following:

```
\section{main section}
\label{sec:mainsection}
 %lots of text
\label{SomethingDescribedButNotDocumentElement}
%more text
```

I want to be able to link to the second label, but it seems those labels are associated with the previous document element (in this case a main section)

So something like:

```
\hyperref[SomethingDescribedButNotDocumentElement]{link to 2nd label}
```

But this jumps up to the `sec:mainsection` label.

- How do I link to an arbitrary section of my document (which may be not described by `section` or `figure` etc)?

Comment: maybe you want to use `\pageref` instead of `\ref`?

Comment: is there another section or do you have 2 labels in the same section?

Comment: there are some good ideas in this question: [When do I need to invoke `\phantomsection`?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44088/).

Comment: @Timebandit this would not be a problem if I did not have two labels in the same section/subsection/etc

Comment: @tohecz Indeed I do have the same problem described there. Feel free to close this as duplicate (I didn't find that earlier, obviously...)

Comment: @enderland It is not really a mistake to ask something that has been here before, as long as you don't mind getting it closed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can generate a new anchor by `\phantomsection`. The syntax of `\hyperref` with optional argument can be used to link an arbitrary text to this location:

```
\phantomsection
\label{SomethingDescribedButNotDocumentElement}

\hyperref[SomethingDescribedButNotDocumentElement]{Something}
```

Comment: Perfect! This is exactly what I needed.

Comment: It is not a bad question. However, we all know that it has been asked many times here. In my opinion, instead of answering it, the duplicate should be found and the question closed.