# Hyperref not working

Tags: hyperref

I have a problem with using `\hyperref` in my LaTeX file. For some reason, after compiling my LaTeX file and opening my `.pdf`, the `\hyperref` doesn't go right to the place where the `\label` is on! And I don't know why it isn't working.

Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage[applemac]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\label{I}Eventos\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ | l | p{5cm} |}
\hline
Nome & Festa do Antonio \\ \hline 
Ano & 2003 \\ \hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
Familias\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ | l | p{5cm} |}
\hline
Data de casamento & 2000 \\ \hline 
Mulher &\hyperref[aut4]{aut4}
\\ \hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
Pessoas\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ | l | p{5cm} |}
\hline
Nome & Manuel da Silva
 \\ \hline 
Data de nascimento & 1977 \\ \hline 
Data de falecimento & 2011 \\ \hline 
Foto & f.jpg \\ \hline 
Hist & h1.tex \\ \hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ | l | p{5cm} |}
\hline
Nome & Ana da Silva
 \\ \hline 
Data de nascimento & 2006 \\ \hline 
Foto & f1.jpg \\ \hline 
Hist & h1.tex \\ \hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ | l | p{5cm} |}
\hline
Nome & Maria Felisbina
 \\ \hline 
Data de nascimento & 1980 \\ \hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\label{aut1}\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ | l | p{5cm} |}
\hline
Nome & Maria da Silva
 \\ \hline 
Data de falecimento & 2009 \\ \hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\label{aut2}\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ | l | p{5cm} |}
\hline
Nome & Joaquim Oliveira da Silva
 \\ \hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\label{aut3}\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ | l | p{5cm} |}
\hline
Nome & Joaquina
 \\ \hline 
Data de nascimento & 1930 \\ \hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\label{aut4}\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ | l | p{5cm} |}
\hline
Nome & Serafim da Silva
 \\ \hline 
Data de nascimento & 2004 \\ \hline 
\end{tabular}\end{center}
\hyperref[I]{I}
\end{document}
```

As you can see, my `\hyperref[aut4]{aut4}` doesn't go to my `\label{aut4}`.

Is there a problem if I first put the `\hyperref` and after the `\label`? (I mean the order)

Comment: You need to set an anchor before `\label{aut4}`, so `\phantomsection\label{aut4}` should work.

Comment: Thank you ! It's working now ! :) 
there is no button for "Answered Question" ?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Incorrect target of `\label` link produced by `hyperref`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/49061/5764)