# 'hyperref' not working in TeXstudio 2.10.8

Tags: code

I have a code where I am using `hyperef`, but to my surprise it is not working. I checked [Hyperref not working [duplicate]](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/117255/hyperref-not-working) also this [Incorrect target of \label link produced by hyperref](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49061/incorrect-target-of-label-link-produced-by-hyperref). However, none worked.
My code

```
%Define symbols for flux, just to make sure it stays consistent throughtout the paper
\def\phie{\ensuremath{\phi_E}}
\def\phib{\ensuremath{\phi_B}}

%Define the derivatives I'll be using, so I don't have to do all the typing every time
\def\dA{\ensuremath{\emph{d}\vec{A}}}
\def\dB{\ensuremath{\emph{d}\vec{B}}}
\def\ds{\ensuremath{\emph{d}\vec{s}}}
\def\dt{\ensuremath{\emph{dt}}}
\def\dphie{\ensuremath{\emph{d}\phie}}
\def\dphib{\ensuremath{\emph{d}\phib}}

\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,draft]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\colorlet{linkequation}{blue}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\usepackage[left=1cm,right=1cm,top=1cm,bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}
\author{Bonjour}
\title{Maxwell's Equation}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Introduction}\label{sec:Introduction}
The properties of electromagnetic fields and waves.
\begin{subequations}
Maxwell's equations:
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\theparentequation.\arabic{equation}}
\begin{align}\phantomsection\label{eq:test}
        \nabla \cdot \mathbf{E} &= \frac {\rho} {\varepsilon_0}, \hspace{84pt} \text{Gauss' Law}\\
        \nabla \cdot \mathbf{B} &= 0,\hspace{92pt} \text{No magnetic monopoles}\\
        \nabla \times \mathbf{E} &= -\frac{\partial \mathbf{B}}{\partial t},\hspace{74pt} \text{Faraday's Law}\\ 
        \nabla \times \mathbf{B} &= \mu_0\left(\mathbf{j} + \varepsilon_0 \frac{\partial \mathbf{E}} {\partial t} \right)\hspace{30pt} \text{Ampère's Law with charge conservation}
\end{align}
In equation \eqref{eq:test}. 
end{document}
```

The link was not a hyperlink but a usual one.

Comment: hyperref warns you: `Package hyperref Warning: Draft mode on.`. Remove the draft option if you want clickable links.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) (basically it means writing `\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}` instead of `\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,draft]{article}`) More info on draft mode [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/49369/64454).

Comment: Thanks a lot, to both. It is a great help. I will try this

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, Eventhough, I have specified blue as a highlight colour but it is coming red in color(output). `\colorlet{linkequation}{blue}`

Comment: Use `\usepackage[colorlinks,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}` if you want blue.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Would you like to write an answer? Or close as "solved in comments"?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as solved in comments