# links not going to the page when clicked

Tags: table-of-contents

My book consists of three parts `\frontmatter`, `\mainmatter` and `\backmatter`. It gives the desired output.

`\frontmatter` consists of titlepage, preface and acknowledgement. In the table of contents when I click on preface or acknowledgement it goes to titlepage.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: Isn't this the same question like this one, made from another account? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/420513/table-of-contents-not-going-to-the-page-when-clicked. Also `\frontmatter` etc. are not really parts, they change the numbering effectively. Please provide the minimal compilable document that has this issue

Comment: Probably related? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/193380/hyperref-pageref-links-point-to-first-page

Comment: Hi I used \addcontentline command to add to toc. Instead I changed it to \chapter{} and it works perfectly.

Comment: @John: A manual `\addcontentsline` alone does of course not work for the link since there is no hyper anchor information -- this is set by using commands `\chapter`, `\section` when `\refstepcounter` is used inside.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/420513/table-of-contents-not-going-to-the-page-when-clicked