# hyperref \hyperlink - pointing to the first page of the document

Tags: hyperref, hyperlink

I am creating a user manual for an ERP software and I am using `\hyperlink{}{}` option to create the links. After clicking on the link, it is pointing to the first page always. I tried the solution given in the link [Hyperref \pageref links point to first page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/193380/hyperref-pageref-links-point-to-first-page?newreg=aed1287cc740443b8a1858fb60456afd) . But the given solution is not working for me.

The code is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}  
\usepackage[top=1.65cm, bottom=2cm, right=1.25cm, left=1.25cm]{geometry}  
\usepackage{subfiles}  
\usepackage{tcolorbox}  
\usepackage{hyperref}  
\newcommand{\hlabel}{\phantomsection\label}  
\hypersetup{hidelinks}  

For defining labels I tried both:  
\section{Module}  
\phantomsection\label{sec:st}  
 and  
\section{Module}  
\label{sec:st}
```

What should I do to correct this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: When you say _the given solution is notworking for me_, do you mean you cannot compile or the result is not what you expect ?

Comment: Your [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) doesn't compile...

Comment: @BambOo, I can compile, but if I click on the hyperlink, it will go to the first page not to  the section which I intended.

Comment: `\hyperlink` and `\hypertarget` use the same name. The hypertarget name for `\label` is generated by `\refstepcounter`. You can find out what it is using `\csname @currentHref\endcsname` or look it up in the aux file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is too long for a comment, but as far as I can see this works as expected without the need for a `\phantomsection` command. I suspect that the problem is a misunderstanding of how the labels work, so let me show this by way of example. The MWE below produces three pages with the sections with labels defined via `\label{sec:st1}` and `\label{sec:st2}` on page 2 and the hyerplinks inserted using `\ref{sec:st1}` and `\ref{sec:st2}` on page 3. The following screenshot shows that the hyerlink is working correctly for `\ref{sec:st2}` (my PDf viewer is skim, which shows these elegant mouse-overs for hyperlinks). As requested in the comments, I have used `\hyperref[sec:st1]{some text}` for the first link to show how to specify your own text for the link.

[image]

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[top=1.65cm, bottom=2cm, right=1.25cm, left=1.25cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcommand{\hlabel}{\phantomsection\label}
\hypersetup{colorlinks}

\begin{document}
  blank page
  \newpage
  For defining labels I tried both:
  \section{Module}
  \label{sec:st1}
   and
  \section{Module}
  \label{sec:st2}

  \newpage some stuff
  \hyperref[sec:st1]{some text}
  and \ref{sec:st2}

\end{document}
```

I have also used `\hypersetup{colorlinks}` to highlight the links (instead of `\hypersetup{idelinks}` in the MWE).
`

Comment: I tried to \hyperlink, because I can enter some text using the command. \hyperlink{label name}{Some Text}.
It is not possible to add texts using \ref command.
What package I should use for this purpose?

Comment: @adhokshajaA.M Use `\hyperref[label]{text}`. See my edit.